# how to send and receive message using direct channels

Tags: spring-integration, spring-kafka

I am triggering xml(http rest API)flow from Java class using

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("request.channel")
MessageChannel httpOutboundGateway;


Message<?> message = MessageBuilder.withPayload("")
                    .setHeader("bstUrl", "http://test-core-api-wcnp.stg.com/api/v1/workflow?userId="1234"&userType="abc")
                    .setHeader("userId", "1234")
                    .setHeader("userType", "abc")
                    .build();

            httpOutboundGateway.send(message);
            
       /* MessagingTemplate template = new MessagingTemplate();
        Message reply = template.sendAndReceive(httpOutboundGateway, message); */
```

My xml looks like this:

```
<int:channel id="request.channel" />
<int:channel id="response.channel" />

<int:gateway id="requestGateway"
             default-request-channel="request.channel">
</int:gateway>

<int:chain id="workload-chain" input-channel="request.channel" output-channel="response.channel">
    <int-http:outbound-gateway id="workflowGateway"
                               url-expression="headers.bstUrl"
                               http-method="GET"
                               expected-response-type="java.lang.String"
                               charset="UTF-8"
                               request-factory="httpComponentClientRequestFactory"
                               mapped-request-headers="*" >
  </int-http:outbound-gateway>
        <int:transformer ref="kafkaTransformer" method="fetchWorkflowCoreServiceResponse" />
</int:chain>
```

I am getting String response in fetchWorkflowCoreServiceResponse method which I am converting into required DTO classes.
but for the following logic, I need to have the above response after I send the message. I thought of calling receive method on response.channel but it needs pollable channel in order do that. but I am using direct channel here.

and if I try to use MessagingTemplate sendAndReceive method, application is giving dispatcher has no subscribers error for response channel.

Can you please help how can I fetch response wherever I want from the response channel?

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption about `template.sendAndReceive()` is correct. Only the problem that you have that `output-channel="response.channel"` on your `chain` for its result. And that's exactly where you got that `dispatcher has no subscribers` error. So, this endpoint (chain) sees that output channel and tries to send the reply over there instead of `replyChannel` header as it is typical for request-reply scenario. It is not clear what is your logic, but an easy fix is to add `<bridge input-channel="response.channel">` and then reply will be sent you back according to the `replyChannel` header.

See more info about gateway and request-reply behavior in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#gateway

Comment: Thanks for your response. even though I removed chain and just have http outbound gateway, somehow I am still getting dispatcher has no subscribers error on template.sendAndReceive() method. would you know what else might have went wrong?

Comment: You have to remove that `output-channel="response.channel"`